# where is Project Darkstar (red dwarf)

Tags: server-side, serversocket

before a days I was search for an open source actionscript server side, I found Project Darkstar (red dwarf) and I save the name in my mind to return to it when I will be free, now I'm free and I want to download it but I don't found it.

what happened to it? if I found the server uploaded can I adopt it as my game sever side ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it appears that RedDwarf server is not being actively worked on.  Although its website (http://www.reddwarfserver.org) is no longer active, the code can be found at https://github.com/reddwarf-nextgen/reddwarf .

Answer (score 1):

[Project Darkstar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Darkstar) began as a personal project of Jeff Kesselman in 1999. It later became a research project at Sun Microsystems, February 2, 2010, Oracle shut down the project, and a community fork has been made called [RedDwarf Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RedDwarf_Server). RedDwarf server is distributed under GPLv2 with the server APIs being made specially available under GPLv2 + classpath exception.

[code in github](https://github.com/reddwarf-nextgen/reddwarf)

[code in sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reddwarf/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  And yes, as you pointed out although the community site is down the repos and wiki still exist.  I'm going to try to add a web page to the pages I host over at wikispaces and watch to see if I can snag the reddwarserver.org name back again.

Jeff Kesselman